# Scrape Specific Div in Python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to scrape text data from a webpage (https://www1.president.go.kr/articles/8863).
The part I want is located in `[[[div class="text left cb text_wrap motion fadeIn visible" data-animation="fadeIn"]]]`. I have tried `soup.find('div', {'class' :'text left cb text_wrap motion fadeIn visible'})` and I am getting nothing.

```
response = requests.get('https://www1.president.go.kr/articles/8863')
if response.status_code == 404:
    print('404: A page could not load')
    exit(1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

data = [] #class="text left cb text_wrap motion fadeIn visible"
html = soup.find('div', {'class' :'text left cb text_wrap motion fadeIn visible'})


# Not returning correctly.
if html is None:
    print('it is not getting data')
    exit(2)
```

What should I type to get that part?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this:

```
html = soup.find('div', {'class' :'text left cb text_wrap motion fadeIn visible'})
```

to  this:

```
html = soup.find('div', {'class' :'text left cb text_wrap motion'})
```

because if you check page source, that div looks like this:

```
<div class="text left cb text_wrap motion" data-animation="fadeIn">
```